# How to Calculate Sum of an Specific property of an Object in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am just trying to calculate the total/sum of values on the time of display, but it is not calculating the sum and also throwing an error

> "could not be converted to int"

Below is the code

```
@foreach ($order->products as $product)
  {{ $product->line_total}}
@endforeach

  {{ $product->line_total->sum() }}
```

In Databse, there are 25 total records, and the matching resultant object is only 8. When I use

```
  {{ $product->sum('line_total') }}
```

it is giving me the sum of all 25 entries instead of 8

Answer (score 0):

You need to sum from the main collection, not the single model:

```
$order->products->sum("line_total")
```

If your `line_total` is another model rather than an integer, first you need to collect that models into a single collection:

```
$line_totals_collection = collect($order->products->pluck("line_total"));
```

Then with that new collection, you can use the sum method:

```
$totals_sum = $line_totals_collection->sum("value");
```

If your summable property is different than `value`, you can use it instead.

Comment: production.ERROR: Object of class Modules\Support\Money could not be converted to int (View:

Comment: Updated my answer.